# setting backbone models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following scenario in a backbone view. I wish to set the model like so.

```
saveField : function(field, val){
    //field = 'username'; val = 'Boris'
model.set({field : val});
}
```

The field is a string representation of an attribute in the model.

The problem is that backbone is creating a new attribute by the name of field.
I can set it like so

```
model.attributes[field] = val;
```

However, I'd rather use set.

Anyone know how I could do this?
thanks

edit: Ended up doing -

```
var asObj = new Object;
asObj[field] = val;
model.set(asObj);
```

Comment: I do it the same way you wound up doing it.

Comment: You could `var asObj = {};` - shorter but yea - key is a string. Also you could `model.attribytes[field] = val;` and `model.changed();` but that much uglier (and afaik "changed:<field>" event won't go off)

Comment: @Paul this actually appears to be built in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the backbone [source](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L185) **this should already work** - your call just needs to look a little different.

```
saveField : function(field, val){
    //field = 'username'; val = 'Boris'
    model.set(field, val);
}
```

The argument format you're looking for is `set(key, value, options)`. This means you can only set one attribute at a time, but it looks like that's all you want to do. The alternative format is `set(attr, options)`, which is what you were using but doesn't work with string keys.

Regardless, you don't want to set the attribute directly as backbone uses this hook internally to do things like raise the 'changed' event.

Comment: Thanks @TheDeeno I didn't know about it already being built in.