# How to set multiple attributes in model (Backbone.js) using strings as keys?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a similar question like this: [setting backbone models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498915/setting-backbone-models) but I need to set multiple attributes, not only one.

So, I have a model in which someone can add custom attributes and I have problem setting them, because if I do it this way:

```
parameter.set({
    name: nameValue, 
    value: valueValue,
    description: descriptionValue
});
```

where `name, value` and `description` are string values, backbone is creating a new attribute by the name of "name", "value" and "description", but I actually need them to be values of the "name" etc.

If I try to do it this way:

```
parameter.set(name, nameValue);
parameter.set(value, valueValue);
parameter.set(description, descriptionValue);
```

backbone creates only the last line: `parameter.set(description, descriptionValue);`

the same thing happens when I try to do it this way:

```
parameter.attributes[name] = nameValue;
parameter.attributes[value] = valueValue;
parameter.attributes[description] = descriptionValue;
```

so, for example, let's say I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="nameValue"/>

<input type="text" id="value"/>
<input type="text" id="valueValue"/>

<input type="text" id="description"/>
<input type="text" id="descriptionValue"/>
```

where:

```
var name = this.$('#name');
var nameValue = this.$('#nameValue');
var value = this.$('#value');
var valueValue = this.$('#valueValue');
var description = this.$('#description');
var descriptionValue = this.$('#descriptionValue');
```

Comment: So do you want to create a `name` with properties `value` and `description`?

Comment: No, I want to put inside parameter attributes that are entered by the user in the textboxes (I updated the code)

Comment: Are you sure that you have the values (they are not null or undefined) of `name` `value` and `description` when you try to update your model?

Comment: it's certainly not backbone issue but some other code, can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can add them like:

```
var name = this.$('#name').val();
var nameValue = this.$('#nameValue').val();
var value = this.$('#value').val();
var valueValue = this.$('#valueValue').val();
var description = this.$('#description').val();
var descriptionValue = this.$('#descriptionValue').val();

var params = {};

if (name) {
    params[name] = nameValue;
}
// the same for other attributes
// ....
// And at the end

model.set(params);
```

`If` statement will ensure that attribute names exists. And then collect them into an empty object. At the end set them at once.

**Update**

Below you can find `working` example of your issue. Fill the inputs and then click submit to stringify the object you wish to construct.

```js
var MyForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#test', 
    events: {
        "click .submit": "showObject" 
    },
    showObject: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var name = this.$('#name').val();
      var nameValue = this.$('#nameValue').val();
      var value = this.$('#value').val();
      var valueValue = this.$('#valueValue').val();
      var description = this.$('#description').val();
      var descriptionValue = this.$('#descriptionValue').val();
      
      var params = {};

      if (name) {
          params[name] = nameValue;
      }
      
      if (value) {
          params[value] = valueValue;
      }
      
      if (description) {
          params[description] = descriptionValue;
      }
      
      
      this.model.set(params);
      
      
      this.$('.test-object').text(JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON()));
    }});

var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var myForm = new MyForm({model: (new TestModel()) });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
  <input type="text" id="nameValue"/>

  <input type="text" id="value"/>
  <input type="text" id="valueValue"/>

  <input type="text" id="description"/>
  <input type="text" id="descriptionValue"/>
  <div class="test-object"></div>
  <button class="submit">Show object</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, no, this isn't right. This solution gives you the same result as the solutions I already mentioned.

Comment: @hlamija I have updated the answer, please check working code snippet.

Comment: For me it's not working :(
It still adds only the last item inside the `params`, not all of them

Comment: @hlamija As you can see from code snippet it is working. I guess you have another issue in your code. Can you console.log each setted param before setting them in a model?